# How to recognize/restore corrupted files after data recovery?

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, fsck, ddrescue

So, I had an `ext4` partition mounted at `/home` that started to fail. After confirming it was a HDD issue, I stopped using it, bought a new one and, from a live USB stick, I formatted the new one and copied the partition using `ddrescue`. Finally, a `fsck` to fix any remaining FS issues:

```bsh
$ sudo ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /root/ddrescue.log
# There were very few bad areas reported (my bad not saving the log file)...
$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1
```

After installing the new drive, things were back to "normal"; most applications worked flawlessly, but some experienced some issues. Tracking those issues to specific configuration files I could see that these were "corrupted", and found this way to check:

```bsh
$ hexdump -C ok.conf 
00000000  5b 63 65 72 74 5d 0a 63  61 5f 66 69 6c 65 3d 0a  |[cert].ca_file=.|
00000010  74 72 75 73 74 65 64 5f  63 65 72 74 3d 65 38 63  |trusted_cert=e8c|
# Truncating output...
$ file ok.conf
ok.conf: ASCII text
```

```bsh
$ hexdump -C corrupt.conf 
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000231
# This output is not truncated.
$ file corrupt.conf 
corrupt.conf: data
```

Even file size don't make sense on the corrupt ones:

```bsh
$ ls -l *.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 561 sep 30 08:36 corrupt.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 561 oct  7 09:21 ok.conf
```

So the question is: **is there a way to identify corrupted files after a recovery? Is there a way to repair these?**

**NOTES**: I still have the original drive with all the data and I can confirm the new drive is OK. After reading further, some people recommend giving `ddrescue` a second run with the retry option (`-r3`) so it can retry in case of a read error, I haven't tried this yet and don't know if it'll make a difference. Maybe someone can shed some light about this too.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to identify corrupted files after a recovery?

There are applications and utilities which can verify certain file types (e.g. images, audio, video, archives) but aside from that many file formats are application specific and cannot be reliably checked.

> Is there a way to repair these?

- Images: no way
- Videos: remove broken frames
- Audio: mute/remove broken sections
- Archives: most archives are "solid", so you can try to restore files up to the point where an archive is damaged but all subsequent files are lost
- Other formats: application dependent